# Code Igniter routing and links

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I am new to CodeIgniter bu I know CakePHP pretty well.

If I rewrite the following:

```
test -> welcome/login
test/(:any) -> welcome/login/$1
```

When I write my links i want to put a link to "welcome/login/asdas" in code and to be parsed as "test/asdas". CakePHP did that using the html link or router::url

EDIT:

What I mean is site_url('welcome/login/asd') should return "test/asd"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is not possible. Actually, CodeIgniter just re-route your app from one URL to other using routes defined previously by yourself in `route.php`

This is the most far that you can go. `site_url` is an internal CodeIgniter function that returns your site URL as you specify in `config.php` file

> **site_url()**
>
> **Returns your site URL, as specified in
>   your config file**. The index.php file
>   (or whatever you have set as your site
>   index_page in your config file) will
>   be added to the URL, as will any URI
>   segments you pass to the function.
>
> You are encouraged to use this
>   function any time you need to generate
>   a local URL so that your pages become
>   more portable in the event your URL
>   changes.
>
> Segments can be optionally passed to
>   the function as a string or an array.
>   Here is a string example:
>
> echo site_url("news/local/123"); The
>   above example would return something
>   like:
>   http://example.com/index.php/news/local/123

I'll try to study `site_url` function located in `url_helper.php` file (`system/helpers/url_helper.php` | Line 42) and modify it to do whatever I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Go to `application/config/routes.php`

You can add the following variable in the `routes.php`

```
$route['test'] = "welcome/login";
$route['test/:any'] = "welcome/login/$1";
```

Browse this http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: I already put the routing in the "routes.php" file. What I was asking is how to use redirect or site_url or other functions from the url helper such as this one to redirect or show the proper url.

Comment: First of all, load the url helper in the controller.

Like, $this->load->helper('url');

And, then use site_url(), redirect().

Please browse this http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html